# Compare ResultSet.getString value to an input from textfield

Tags: java, ms-access, resultset

Whenever I press log-in it shows the catch message.

tried setting it to ResultSet.getString(name of column in access).equal(value of textfield)

```java
b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener () 
        {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                try
                {
                    String u1=t1.getText();
                    String u2=t2.getText();

                    if (u1==rs.getString("Name") || u2==rs.getString("Pass"))
                    {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Success");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid");
                }
            }
        });
```

It always shows catch message which is "Invalid".
Also I am using Ucanaccess for my program to connect with MS access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String comparison should be done using the equals method

```
  if (u1.equals(rs.getString("Name")) || u2.equals(rs.getString("Pass")) {
```

**Edit:**

Also, add ex.printStackTrace(); in your code in case there is an issue

```
catch (Exception ex)
  {
    ex.printStackTrace();   
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid");
  }
```

Just assuming you comparing user name and password, in this case, you should use **&&** instead of **||**

Comment: Thanks responding but it still returns Invalid

Comment: put  ex.printStackTrace();    in your code, as mentioned in the edit section, there seems some issue in your code, most likely issue with resultset

Comment: Thank you when I added ex.printStackTrace(); error showed that my ResultSet was set before the first row so there was nothing to compare it to.